# What is the purpose of resistor Ra in this simple vaccum tube voltage amplifier circuit?

Tags: amplifier, load, vacuum-tube

Came across this in a book, there's a brief explanation of why there's said resistor in the circuit:

" ... it should be obvious that if we apply an audio
signal voltage to the grid (i.e., vary the grid voltage)
then current in the valve is bound to vary too. We can
put this current variation to good use by putting a
resistance in series with the valve so that a
corresponding audio voltage is generated across the
resistor, which is also called the load. "

Yet I can't quite understand the need for the resistor to be there in order to create the second amplified voltage signal, won't the amplified voltage signal be there anyway whether there's a resistor or not?

[image: Circuit picture]

Comment: Are you considering replacing the resistor with a short or an open?

Comment: None, I'm not yet actually building this but trying to get the concept/theory of why each element in the circuit is placed there and what is it doing. :)

Comment: Okay, but you asked "what if the resistor weren't there"? Which situation are you asking about? Replacing it with a short, or with an open?

Comment: Oh right, short.

Comment: Tubes as often designed as "valves" because they act like a current valves. Since they are voltage driven, it is necessary to turn their output current variations into voltage variations. U = R × I a simple resistor makes this job.

Comment: Of course, greg! This comment made it all clear, could you post it as a reply so I can mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2):

Consider if Ra were a dead short (zero ohms).  The voltage at the plate would always be 300 volts, regardless of the grid voltage.  The *current* would vary, but the voltage would remain constant.

Comment: Right, so, to "separate" the amplified voltage signal from the constant 300 voltage feed so to speak?

Comment: @raz: yes.  the plate load resistor is there for the same reason a collector load resistor is present in a transistor amplifier.

Answer (score 0):

Viewing the vacuum tube as a transconductor, that is a box producing changes in OUTPUT CURRENT when the INPUT (GRID) VOLTAGE changes, we have this I-V plot:

[image: schematic]

How to compute the VoltageGain of this triode_with_Rload? Just as you do for a Bipolar with a Collector Load Resistor: multiply GM * Rload.
If this triode has 1 milliMho (milliSiemen) at the operating point (say -2volt on Grid is the Operating point, then Av = 0.001 * 30,000 = 30x. Or 31dB.